# Using an array returned from a member function, is this ok?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Just wondering if I could get some feedback on what I'm doing and whether or not it's bad juju.

I have a member function that returns an 2D array (double indirection pointer) and it looks like...

```
int** ClassName::GetArr() const
{
   return arr;
}
```

...and I would use is like so...

```
if (my_class_object.GetArr()[i][j] == 1) // do something
```

...is this ok?

(And yes, I should probably be using a vector, but the question remains!)

Comment: Stay safe and use a vector.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Agreed, but in this case the OP would want a vector of vectors. ;)

Comment: make sure arr is a `new`ed, not address of local variable or array

Comment: Thanks everyone! I picked based off of who was first because I thought all the answers were good.

Comment: It depends. What is `arr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is but be carefull with out of range errors. and bad access.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to use it like

```
if (my_class_object.GetArr()[i][j] == 1)
```

you might be better providing a getter in the `ClassName`

```
int ClassName::GetValue(int i, int j) const
{
    //possible error checking
    return arr[i][j];
}
```

and obviously call like this

```
if (my_class_object.GetValue(i, j) == 1)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that form be the `const` variant, where there is a corresponding variant that returns a reference for modification.

Comment: Yes. Oops. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, provided `arr` has memory allocated and is initialised/set-up properly, that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is allocated as an array of pointers to double, and then each row is allocated in a second level, then it's fine.

If the array is not fully allocated in both dimensions, it's unlikely to work as expected, and "weird things" happens when you try to access the array.

Using `std::vector<std::vector<double>>& GetArr()` would make it much simpler and safer.

Answer (score 0):

As always when using pointers, you'll have to make sure you're actually accessing valid memory locations.

You can also remove one indirection at the expense of a little more index calculation overhead. A 2D array can also be represented by a 1D array which can be accessed like this:

```
my_class_object.GetArr()[i * height + j]
```

In this case, Mats Petersson's suggestion to use a `std::vector` of `std::vector`s can be reduced to a single vector:

```
const std::vector<int>& ClassName::GetArr() const // assuming read-only access
{
  return arr;
}
```

No matter what you do, using the subscript operator can also trigger an access violation because it essentially has the same effect as accessing a C-array pointing to invalid storage.

It's easy to protect yourself against that, however:

```
size_t index                = i * height + j;
const std::vector<int>& vec = my_class_object.GetArr();
if(index < vec.size())
{
    // do stuff using the value at the calculated index
}
```

**EDIT**: Just to spare you confusion, the indices i and j need to be in [0, HEIGHT( and [0, WIDTH( respectively, where height and width are the dimensions of the array in y and x.